# play sound while condition is true

Tags: c++, sdl

I have two images, when the ball image touches the other image I want a sound to be played. This is my code:

```
while (((dstX + 31) > wallRect.x) && ((dstX + 31) < (wallRect.x+30)) && (dstY < (wallRect.y + wallRect.h)) && ((dstY + 31) > wallRect.y))  //31 = ball dimension.
{
    Mix_PlayMusic(soundEffect, -1);
}
```

When the first image leaves the second image the sound still plays. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't possibly work. Why do you even have a `while` loop there? This is just going to call Mix_PlayMusic() over and over again, regardless of whether the music is already playing or not. As a side effect, this loop will consume all your CPU, regardless of whether its condition evaluates to `true` or `false`.

The way this is normally done, is to have a check somewhere inside your central event loop, and check there whether the images intersect, and whether they were intersecting in the previous iteration of the event loop. This is how you decide whether to start of stop the music.

Comment: Second this, your code snippet shows that you have a flaw in your program logic. Unfortunately this does not translate to "play the music while the balls are colliding", and note that usually sound libraries only need one call to whatever `Play()` function to play the music (then one `Stop()` to stop it when desired).

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` instead of `while`, or at least check if the music is playing before calling play function.